# Convert IPv6 address into an ASCII string in Internet standard dotted-decimal format

Tags: c++, winapi, ipv6, ipv4

To convert IPv4 address into an ASCII string in Internet standard dotted-decimal format we use `inet_ntoa` function. What function shuold I use for IPv6?

Comment: IPv6 addresses are not written in dotted decimal format. Take a look at http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5952

Comment: `getnameinfo` with the `NI_NUMERICHOST` flag [per this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1598774/175849).

Comment: getnameinfo with the NI_NUMERICHOST for ipv6 will return normal ipv6 format (i.e. not dotted decimal ip).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent function for IPv6 is `inet_ntop`. In fact this can do IPv4 as well as 6 so is worth using anyway.