# How to use C to read the current IP address?

Tags: c, linux, networking

I have 2 routers. One is 10.0.0.1, another is 100.100.1.1. I have an embedded Untuntu device. The device is connected to one of the routers. When I unplug the cable from one router and plug it to another one, there are 2 IP addresses listed by using the command "ip a":

```
6: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:40:ae:11:26:81 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.172/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 1995218500sec preferred_lft 1995218500sec
    inet 100.100.1.137/24 brd 100.100.1.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 1995218500sec preferred_lft 1995218500sec
    inet6 fe80::240:aeff:fe11:2681/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

By switching the router a few more times, there are always 2 IP Addresses show up in "ip a". But I need to know what the current IP address is.

If I use "ip monitor" to monitor it. The correct IP address shows up when the cable is plugged in the new router like this:

```
6: eth0    inet 10.0.0.172/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 1995873860sec preferred_lft 1995873860sec
```

I tried the sample code from https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html to read the IP. But I got:

```
eth0      AF_INET (2)
                address: <10.0.0.172>
eth0      AF_INET (2)
                address: <100.100.1.137>
```

I also tried [C code to get the IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570511/c-code-to-get-the-ip-address). I got the wrong IP address. It always returns the first IP from the list which is 10.0.0.172 even if the real IP is 100.100.1.137.

How to use C to read the current IP address?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Linux machines do not have "current IP address".  Each ethernet interface has zero or more IP addresses.  From the machines point of view, all addresses listed by `ip a` are valid.  What you *really* want to find out, is the most recent IP address lease obtained by the DHCP client in your device.  The simplest is to add a `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/save-ip-addr` script, that echoes `$ip_address` to a file, say `/etc/dhcp/$interface-current_ip_address`, read-only by all except root.  Then, your program can simply read that file.

Comment: Maybe you can configure Linux to bring down the interface and remove IP address when removal of the cable is detected. That would be a question for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You might also be interested in `ip route`. If your Internet works, presumably the routing table is correct.

Comment: Thanks @Blabbo is Verbose. What save-ip-addr looks like? I don't know what I can put in save-ip-addr. I tried this: change RUN="yes" in /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/debug. Then I run "sudo dhclient -r", and "sudo dhclient". I noticed /tmp/dhclient-script.debug showing the info of released and renewed IP. But if I manually switch the cable to different router, /tmp/dhclient-script.debug remains no change. I don't know how "ip monitor" can get the new IP address. Let me know if you have more info. Thanks!